# Azure Key-Vault Restore

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I'm using Azure Key Vault, to store my encryption keys. After finishing my free trial, I did not update my subscription. So I lost everything. How can I restore all my keys?

Comment: Contact Azure support

Answer (score 0):

After finishing the free trial, any products you’ve deployed will be decommissioned and you won’t be able to access them, your option is to upgrade it to a [pay-as-you-go](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0003p/) account.

See - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-faq/

[image]